# Jump to next occurrence of the current character

Tags: key-bindings, search, navigation

I often navigate to the next occurrence of the current non-paren character. For example,

```
`HTTP GET www.example.com/example/com` is an example URL.
```

When the cursor is at the beginning of the line at the `` ` `` character, it is useful to jump the the next occurrence of the `` ` ``.

This can be achieved by `` f` `` ([How to jump to a specific character in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402607/how-to-jump-to-a-specific-character-in-vim)), but I winder if I'm missing any single-character shortcut. If not, I'd be happy to know what's the right way to map such a key binding please.

**How do I navigate to the next occurrence of the current character with s single keystroke?**

Comment: See this cross-site dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702427/4748017 and the very closely related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12307/5298

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky and working only for predefined pair of characters, but you can leverage `matchit` plugin, found [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21010756/7796750):

```
:let b:match_words='`\<:\>`'
```

Then you can alternate with `%`, though it may have caveats (see `:help b:match_words`).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a more general solution. I assume we can keybind it somewhow.

Comment: I guess you will need at least 2 key strokes to trigger the mapping and specify a character. There is probably a plugin for your use case, (not) like those which jump to a location specified by 2 characters: `vim-seek` and `vim-sneak`.

Comment: It could easily be mapped to a single keystroke. See the two similar questions I linked to in the comment to the question.

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't think of `yl:normal f<C-R>"<CR>` which effectively copies the character under the cursor and pastes it after `f`.